# routing component outside framework

Tags: php, laravel

i have simple composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "illuminate/routing": "4.1.*"
    }
}
```

And index.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$router = new Illuminate\Routing\Route();

$router->get('/', function(){
   echo 'test';
});
```

What additionally code do you need to run routing?

Answer (score 6):

Right now some of Laravel's components are not designed in a way to make them easy to use separate.

However, with some hacking I got it to work:

index.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$dispatcher = new Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
$router = new Illuminate\Routing\Router($dispatcher);

$router->get('/', function(){
   return 'test';
});

$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $router->dispatch($request);
$response->send();
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "illuminate/routing": "4.1.*",
        "illuminate/events": "4.1.*"
    }
}
```

And you will need to setup the pretty URIs for Laravel [as normal](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess).

Comment: In reality they are pretty well designed, they don't actually rely on Laravels exact implementation, they rely on an implementation of the interface which is a great way of decoupling the components without having a lot of duplicated code, it would make no sense to duplicate the Request interface inside the  router just so they could be used separately..